# How to test DatePickerIOS

Tags: detox

I need to enter a day using the native IOS DatePicker. How do I spin the control wheel to a certain value that might not be in the view, since this starts out with the current date?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detox 7.3.x supports interaction with iOS `UIPickerView`. Match `UIPickerView` by type, and interact with it.

```
await expect(element(by.type('UIPickerView'))).toBeVisible();
await element(by.type('UIPickerView')).setColumnToValue(1,"6");
await element(by.type('UIPickerView')).setColumnToValue(2,"34");
```

Docs are here:
https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#setcolumntovaluecolumnvalue--ios-only

Comment: Nice! Detox is the best!

Comment: Then you probably want to: `await element(by.label('Confirm')).tap();`

Answer (score 2):

datetimepicker have Detox test you can check code here:

https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker/blob/master/example/e2e/detoxTest.spec.js#L54

```
if (global.device.getPlatform() === 'ios') {
      const testElement = await element(
        by.type('UIPickerView').withAncestor(by.id('dateTimePicker')),
      );
      await testElement.setColumnToValue(0, 'November');
      await testElement.setColumnToValue(1, '3');
      await testElement.setColumnToValue(2, '1800');

      await expect(dateTimeText).toHaveText('11/03/1800');
    } else {
       // for Android
    }
```